# FOSUserBundle doesn't send email account validation

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

i'm developing an app using Symfony, and I want to send a validation email for each register. Here is my code:

```
#config.yml
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address:        "example@mail.com"
        sender_name:    Demo Registration
    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled: true
        service:
        mailer:               fos_user.mailer.default
        email_canonicalizer:  fos_user.util.canonicalizer.default
        token_generator:      fos_user.util.token_generator.default
        username_canonicalizer:  fos_user.util.canonicalizer.default
        user_manager:         fos_user.user_manager.default


#parameters.yml
    parameters:
        database_host: 127.0.0.1
        database_port: null
        database_name: @name
        database_user: @user
        database_password: @password
        mailer_transport: smtp 
        mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
        mailer_user: @mail
        mailer_password: @password
        secret: @secret
```

I want to use gmail as email sender. 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide an working E-Mail account, else the system can't send any mails.

You need to provide the information in your parameters.yml

```
mailer_transport: smtp 
mailer_host: YOUR EMAIL HOST
mailer_user: YOUR EMAIL USER
mailer_password: YOUR EMAIL PASS
```

-- UPDATE --

try to format your config.yml correctly:

```
service:
    mailer:               fos_user.mailer.default
    email_canonicalizer:  fos_user.util.canonicalizer.default
    token_generator:      fos_user.util.token_generator.default
    username_canonicalizer:  fos_user.util.canonicalizer.default
    user_manager:         fos_user.user_manager.default
```

instead of

```
service:
mailer:               fos_user.mailer.default
email_canonicalizer:  fos_user.util.canonicalizer.default
token_generator:      fos_user.util.token_generator.default
username_canonicalizer:  fos_user.util.canonicalizer.default
user_manager:         fos_user.user_manager.default
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but I've already tried it and it doesn't work.

Comment: @JonathanMartínez go on the console and try with `app/console swiftmailer:email:send` to send yourself and email. If you don't receive it, there's something wrong with the credentials.

Comment: I've tried it, but this error appears: Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "@mail" using 1 possible authenticators

Comment: @JonathanMartínez `@mail` is no valid entry. abcd@mail.com would be valid as example.

Comment: Yes, I know. It was an example, my mail is like example@gmail.com

Comment: if you're using gmail, you need to configure it that way: http://symfony.com/doc/current/email/gmail.html

Comment: Now I can send emails, but the validation account email is not sent.